# Get two values from same table using SELECT - JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables - Materials, Activities and Units.
Both the materials and activities table are related to the units table by containing an `unit_id` property. How do I get both the unit of the activity and the unit of the material with a single query?

This is my current query:

```
SELECT u.username, m.name, a.name, un.name
FROM users u
JOIN materials m
ON (m.id = u.material_id)
JOIN activities a
ON (a.id = u.activity_id)
JOIN units un
ON (un.id = m.unit_id OR un.id = a.unit_id)
```

However I only get one unit returned with it, I want to get both the unit of the material and the unit of the activity. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the `units` table twice

```
SELECT u.username, 
       m.name as m_name, unm.name as m_unit,
       a.name as a_name, una.name as a_unit
FROM users u
JOIN materials m ON m.id = u.material_id
JOIN activities a ON a.id = u.activity_id
JOIN units unm ON unm.id = m.unit_id
JOIN units una ON una.id = a.unit_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a sub query for this, it comes in handy for situations like this:

```
SELECT u.username, 
       (SELECT name FROM m WHERE m.id = u.material_id), 
       (SELECT name FROM a WHERE a.id = u.activity_id)
   FROM users
```